# How to align 4 images as 2*2 in HTML?

Tags: html

I have been trying to align four images that are to be displayed as the pic below. But I have been getting spaces after each row. How can I remove them?

[image: Example Image]

Also is there a way that I can add a small thumbnail of the example image in the middle where all four images meet?

Along with this I am also trying to add captions over the images. Currently they are displayed below the images. How can I add them over the images?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body alink="ff0000" bgcolor="ffffff" link="0000ff" text="000000" vlink="800080">

<div>
<div class="transbox" style="width: 50%; height=50%; float: left;">
<img  src="https://s22.postimg.org/61txkvgch/Venture_Capital.jpg" width="100%" />
<div style="position: relative; top:50%; left:45%; width:200px; height:25px">
  <center>
     <font color="Black" size="+2">Looking Into The Future</font>
  </center>
</div> 

<img  src="https://s11.postimg.org/zf842w1mb/Real_Estate.jpg" width="100%" />
<div style="    text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
  <center>
     <font color="Black" size="+2">correct one</font>
  </center>
 </div> 
 </div>
 </div>

<div>
<div class="transbox" style="width: 50%; height=50%; float: right;">
<img  src="https://s18.postimg.org/acomst9gp/image.jpg" width="100%" />
<div style="position: relative; top:50%; left:45%; width:200px; height:25px">
  <center>
     <font color="Black" size="+2">Looking Into The Future</font>
  </center>
 </div> 

 <img  src="https://s13.postimg.org/8yima8xvb/Construction.jpg" width="100%" />
 <div style="position: relative; top:50%; left:45%; width:200px; height:25px">
  <center>
     <font color="Black" size="+2">Looking Into The Future</font>
  </center>
 </div> 
</div>
</div>




</div></body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/8bL4qqr8/

Comment: Use hero images for adding captions over images.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
   background-color:"ffffff";
}

.img-grid{
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  height:400px;
}

.img-grid img{
  width :100%;
  height:400px;
}
.caption{
  display :none;
}

.img-grid:hover .caption{
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transbox img-grid">
    <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/61txkvgch/Venture_Capital.jpg" />
    <div  class="caption">
            <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="transbox img-grid">
    <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/zf842w1mb/Real_Estate.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
            <p>Looking into the future</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="transbox img-grid">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/acomst9gp/image.jpg" />
    <div  class="caption">
            <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="transbox img-grid">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/8yima8xvb/Construction.jpg" />
    <div  class="caption">
            <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of deprecated stuff in your HTML. Don't use all this link, text stuff in your body. And not `<center>` or `<font>` otherwise. I made a simple snippet of the stuff your wanted with flexbox. I modified your code a bit. You can find browser support for flexbox here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.transbox {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.transbox .thumbnail {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}
.transbox:nth-of-type(1) .thumbnail {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.transbox:nth-of-type(2) .thumbnail {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.transbox:nth-of-type(3) .thumbnail {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.transbox:nth-of-type(4) .thumbnail {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.transbox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.transbox .text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="transbox">
    <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/61txkvgch/Venture_Capital.jpg" />
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/61txkvgch/Venture_Capital.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="transbox">
    <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/zf842w1mb/Real_Estate.jpg" />
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/zf842w1mb/Real_Estate.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Looking into the future</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="transbox">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/acomst9gp/image.jpg" />
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/acomst9gp/image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="transbox">
    <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/8yima8xvb/Construction.jpg" />
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://s13.postimg.org/8yima8xvb/Construction.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Looking Into The Future</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't the thumbnail though I require in the meeting point of all four images but the example image itself. I have also been trying to zoom those images on hover, but it zooms in the background. I tried to scale it using `.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }`
`.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.3); }` ; but it still won't go fullscreen.

Comment: Maybe you should phrase your question again to include the wanted behavior etc. You should also consider asking all these separate questions on their on.

Comment: "decrepitated" <- I need to start using this more

Comment: @j08691 I'm so sorry for my mistake. Must have been the first "spell check option" or something. But I'm glad if English is your native language (I assume) and you have the time to correct these spelling mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;

  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;

  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<div class="grow" style="    width: 40%;    position: fixed;    top: 50%;    left: 50%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<img class=" align:center"; src="https://s14.postimg.org/6ufixiest/Logo.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://vindhyaassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/IT-1.jpg" alt="pepsi">

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://vindhyaassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RealEstate1.jpg" alt="pepsi"  >

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://vindhyaassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/VentureCapital-1.jpg" alt="pepsi"  >

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://vindhyaassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Construction-1.jpg" alt="pepsi"  >

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>

<div style="    width: 20%;    position: fixed;    top: 25%;    left: 25%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<h1 id="text">
    Construction/Interior Design - Build to Live
  </h1>
</div>
</div>

<div style="    width: 20%;    position: fixed;    top: 25%;    left: 75%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<h1 id="text">
    Real Estate - Buy and Sell Potential Properties
  </h1>
</div>
</div>

<div style="    width: 20%;    position: fixed;    top: 75%;    left: 25%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<h1 id="text">
     Information Technology - Handling Potential IT Projects
  </h1>
</div>
</div>

<div style="    width: 20%;    position: fixed;    top: 75%;    left: 75%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<h1 id="text">
    Venture Capital - Finance for High Growth Potential
  </h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="grow" style="    width: 20%;    position: fixed;    top: 50%;    left: 50%;    margin-top: -100px;    margin-left: -10%;">
<div>
<img class=" align:center"; src="https://s14.postimg.org/6ufixiest/Logo.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```