# Can't bring images up HTML

Tags: html, css

Hey I'm trying to get a website for a server I'm hosting and I'm trying to bring the bottom two images up into the open area above them.

Can anyone help me out I can't wrap my head around this, i'm also new to stack overflow so I'm not as fast as some people I'm sorry, it also won't let me post because there was too much code so I took out the css.

So Here is a "JSFiddle" link to the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4hy7q2ou/2/

[image]

```html
    <body>
        <div class="card1 one" style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <img src="css/images/10.png" width="480" height="270"/>
        </div>

        <div class="card1 two" style="margin-top: 60px;">
            <img src="css/images/4.png" width="480" height="270"/>
        </div>

        <div class="card2 one">
            <h2>
                Our Server.
            </h2>
            <p>
                
            </p>
            <p>
                
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="card3 two">
            <h2>
                Our Staff Team.
            </h2>
            <h3>
                Owners:
            </h3>
            <dl>
                Inc0gnitoON
                IgnitionON
            </dl>
            <h3>
                Admins:
            </h3>
            <dl>
                N/A
            </dl>
            <h3>
                Moderators:
            </h3>
            <dl>
                WitherVoid_
            </dl>
        </div>
    </body>
    <body>
        <div class="card1 three" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <img src="css/images/7.png" width="480" height="270"/>
        </div>

        <div class="card1 four">
            <img src="css/images/9.png" width="480" height="270"/>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Please post the code, not a picture of the code.

Comment: Im sorry guys, im new to this and i'm trying but it won't let me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried adding a margin-bottom to the CSS?

Comment: @Insula yes I have and it just made the page longer

Comment: okay you might want to make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code then link it within your question, so we can see your entire code and help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4hy7q2ou/2/ if that works, it's all at the bottom in the features section in the css

Answer (score 0):

You should just align all the images into a square, this is good for cleaner and minimal code:

CSS:

```
img { 
    width:20%; 
    display:inline-table; 
    margin:5px; 
}
```

*I just did "img" but you can actually make this a class e.g. ".card"*

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> 
    <br>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> 
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

[This link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp) could also help you achieve this, if my post doesn't help or if you don't quite understand.

**EDIT**: This should align two images, may need to mess around with the numbers in the CSS to get it to fit better:

CSS:

```
.block { 
    width:20%; 
    display:inline-table; 
    margin:5px; 
} 
.side {  
    display:inline; 
    margin-left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -20%;
} 
.second { 
    display:inline; 
    margin-left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -1%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="block"/> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="block"/> 
    <br>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="block"/> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="block"/> 
</div> 

<div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300" class="side"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300" class="second"/>
</div>
```

Comment: can I also add the 2 long ones on the right side of it too?

Comment: I have added images to align to the right side, hopefully that solves your issue. As I said in the question, you may want to mess around with the numbers in the CSS to get a better fit. You could also check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507999/how-to-align-4-images-as-22-in-html) for how to align images.